# Remapping a topic inside a controller?

Tags: control, ros, roslaunch, remapping, remap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a ros-controls controller publishing a topic, and I'd like to remap that topic with a roslaunch `<remap>` tag. I tried applying the remap to both the controller spawner and the hardware interface node, and neither seemed to take.

Is there some other method required?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191852/remapping-a-topic-inside-a-controller?/) by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1153 on 2014-09-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [timster](https://answers.ros.org/users/3358/timster/) on 2014-09-03**:
Please post your launch file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not possible at present, per this discussion here:

https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/issues/126

---

Originally posted by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) with karma: 1153 on 2014-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1